# Prestashop : Save additional field from product page in database

Tags: database, field, product, prestashop

I have Added 2 text box in product page to recive height an width from user for each product.
I have used textbox input just like quantity in The buy-block Form.
Now I want to save this textboxs in Database  and use them in cart page and order page for each cart and product.
I added 2 variable in cartcontroller.php like $qty in function preProcess() .
Now how can I save them in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you want your customers to submit custom values along the product they order.

In this case, you should look for "product customization" fetaure of PrestaShop :
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Adding+Products+and+Product+Categories#AddingProductsandProductCategories-ManagingCustomization

You can add textbox on product page, customers will type values, these values wiil be displayed on cart and order detail.

Comment: Thank youu.wih your solution i have to add customization for each product and I have many diffrent products.also I put multiple of this 2 fields with jqury event in quantity for area

Comment: IMHO Product Customization is the best way to do it since it's well integrated in the order workflow. You can still add a jquery-ed textbox to compute the area. The only cons is the need to add it for each product.